# Проблема с кодировкой в Qt Creator

Tags: visual-c++, qt, c++, creator

Всем доброго времени суток.

Осваиваю Qt Creator (Windows 7, компилятор от MS VS 2010). Пытаюсь написать избитое:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    std::wcout << L"Привет, мир!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

На выходе получаю невнятные крякозябры.
Скажите, что я делаю не так?

З.Ы. И да, я знаю, про библиотеки Qt, но у меня стоит задача и разбирать STL-ный код, и писать новый на Qt, поэтому я начал с более привычного. Увы, неудачно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нужно все-таки определиться с тем какая кодировка у файла исходного кода. Я запросто могу набить сишный файл, который будет не в CP1251, а в UTF-8, c соответствующим результатом для компиляции. Также попробуйте писать сообщения латиницей - по идее с ней проблем быть не должно. А помочь локализовать проблему это может, но отчасти.
2. Зачем Вы используете строковые литералы? Если уж погнали использовать Qt, то может все-таки воспользоваться встроенными возможностями по локализации программ? И забыть про кошмар с std::wcout и std::wstring? Посмотрите [QString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html), [QTextCodec](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html#codecForLocale) и [QTranslator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtranslator.html)